# Do we need to store access token both on client and server side?

Tags: c#, security, authentication, oauth, identityserver4

My question is - Do we need to store access token both on client and server side?

Identity Server 4 store access tokens for us, as far as I know, so we don't have to worry about that, but do we have to manage storing access token in the client side (e.g. cookie in browser)?

Comment: This question should probably be more specific. Can you provide details of the nature of your client application(s) any and other relevant information please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically yes, you'll need to store the access token on the client side. Assuming you want to call APIs repeatedly with that access token, you'll need to store in memory. If your Client lives in a browser (i.e. Javascript) you'll need to store it in a cookie or local storage. If you have a non-browser Client and you want to survive restarts, you'll need to store it on persistent storage, i.e. disk.

The only exception to all of this are Clients that only need to call an API once, which is a rare case.